# Is it possible to reference a Visual Studio SQL project from a non-database project in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I currently am working with an ASP application that includes an Entity Framework model. I would like to separate the model out of this ASP project so that it can be referenced by other projects in an isolated way.

I can think of two ways of managing a SQL Server project:

1. A project that ONLY has an Entity Framework model, and then referencing that from 2 or more ASP/console/etc projects
2. Using a SQL database project, and referencing that from the other C# projects

I have a POC for option (1), where I can see the types defined in the Entity Framework model project. I would like to see if it's possible to do the same thing using a SQL project...

I see that I can reference a database project from a non-database project, but I don't know how to use it...

Normally I would import a namespace in the `.CS` file I'm working on, and that would provide me types defined in that namespace. But so far as I know there are no concepts such as 'namespaced' defined in a database project.

I would like something along the lines of:

```
DB project <-- referenced by model in ASP project
```

This would allow me to reference the SQL Server database project's tables as types (in my imagination at least). Is this possible?

Comment: *This would allow me to reference the SQL Server database project's tables as types*? Database tables are not represented by C# classes unless you use an ORM like Entity Framework to either generate the classes for you or map between a type that you create yourself and a table in the database. How are you supposed to "reference" an actual database table from a C# project? This makes no sense. You may read from and write to the table if you know its name but that's another story.

Comment: You have an active imagination, but nothing will happen by itself. The closest you can get that way is configuring your build so the database project is automatically deployed on build (to a LocalDB instance) from which EF then generates its model (using the database first approach). This requires some careful tinkering with the build order/steps, though. Going the opposite way with code first in EF is the path of lesser resistance.

Comment: Create a Class Project with the code for the database in the class.

Comment: Thank you @JeroenMostert - I was hoping that Entity Framework would be able to use a database project as it's base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This would allow me to reference the SQL Server database project's tables as types (in my imagination at least).

Not really. A database project is used to create new or update existing databases. Unlike object relational mappers (ORMs), such as for example Entity Framework, they don't generate any .NET classes that you can consume directly in from .NET application or class library.

To consume a database from a .NET application you will first have to connect to a deployed version of it, and without using an ORM you will then have to write SQL queries and commands yourself to talk with it.

It makes no sense to add a reference to a database project. The database project simply defines the schema for the database. It has to be deloyed somewhere where the .NET application can connect to it.

Comment: In general I would prefer to write SQL code inline, since I find that ORMS only really help with simple SQL. Therefore all they really do is stop people practicing SQL and make them unable to write complex queries when they otherwise would have been able to. Thus lowering salary potential. In this case the code already exists and I don't want to re-write it to refactor away the ORM